# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: The fault message 'tns:GetWebAuthByKeyFaultDetail' must have a single part

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am getting this error when I run SOAP API in SOAP client:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: The fault message 'tns:GetWebAuthByKeyFaultDetail' must have a single part

Here's my code:

```
$xml = 'request';

$wsdl = "https://wsdl?wsdl";

$local_cert = "location";

$options = array(
  'uri'=>$local_cert,
  'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
  'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
  'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
  'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'connection_timeout'=>15,
  'trace'=>true,
  'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
  'exceptions'=>true,
);
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = $soap->__soapCall("GetWebAuthByKey",$xml);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
var_dump($data);

print_r($data);

die;
```

Comment: "The fault message must have a single part" is a quote from the WSDL specification. It sounds like the WSDL is not valid. https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-wsdl-20010315#_soap:fault

Comment: Ok ,thank you for the reply.

Comment: it is valid i am getting full xml file while reun this wsdl in browser

Comment: Please help me some one ,i am stucked with this error